# Javascript array how to properly clone values to another array . Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component, and I want to add a value to the beginning of the array, but I have an error. Whats wrong, tell me please?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DaoMockService } from '../../services/dao/dao-mock.service';
import { MatTableDataSource, } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-table',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-table.component.css']
})
export class DynamicTableComponent implements OnInit {

  data;

  model = 
        {
            label: "Table label",
            extra: [
                "edit",
                "select"
            ],
            columns: [
                'color', 
                'desde', 
                'nombre'
            ]
        }

        dataFields: any[] = this.model.columns
        tableColumns: any[] = this.model.columns


  constructor(private dao: DaoMockService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createTable()
  }

  createTable() {

    console.log("dataFields --->", this.dataFields)
    // output: 
    // dataFields ---> (3) ["color", "desde", "nombre"]

    console.log("tableColumns --->",this.tableColumns)
    // output: 
    // tableColumns ---> (3) ["color", "desde", "nombre"]

    this.tableColumns.unshift("edit")

    console.log("dataFields --->", this.dataFields)
    // output: 
    // dataFields ---> (4) ["edit", "color", "desde", "nombre"]

    console.log("tableColumns --->",this.tableColumns)
    // output: 
    // tableColumns ---> (4) ["edit", "color", "desde", "nombre"]

    this.dao.getAll().subscribe( (res:any) => this.data = new MatTableDataSource(res.data.content))
  }

}
```

this.tableColumns.unshift("edit") unshifts both  dataFields and
 tableColumns arrays

Comment: dataFields: any[] = this.model.columns
        tableColumns: any[] = this.model.columns are pointing to the same

Comment: yes. but I use "unshift" only to one array, not to both

Comment: Please don't copy and paste Lorem Impsum's Wikipedia page here. Instead, do what the error is telling you; explain your code, tell us what the actual error is, etc.. See [ask].

Comment: i didnt know what to add more, all of explanation was above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
dataFields: any[] = this.model.columns
     tableColumns: any[] = this.model.columns
```

this means     `dataFields: any[] = tableColumns: any[] = this.model.columns` 
both varaiables store the reference to the same array

Try this

```
 dataFields: any[] = this.model.columns
 tableColumns: any[] = [...this.model.columns] // Spread operator creates a new array and assings it to tableColumns
```

Read more [here](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array)

Comment: Please explain to him with your answer why his code didn't work :) it's useful for other people who don't get why it doesn't work

Comment: Edited post pls check

Answer (score 0):

this question is related to the differences between Reference and value in Javascript. Initially can be confusing, but along you learn and get the practice you understand the basic fundamentals of the language.
Below, there are some useful links you can read to know more about why your array share the same reference.

[explaining value vs reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

[Learning how references work in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this

```
dataFields: any[] = this.model.columns
tableColumns: any[] = this.model.columns
```

you are assigning the reference to model.columns, It's actually not creating a new array.
One way to do is use the spread operator "..."

```
dataFields: any[] = [...this.model.columns]
```

Or if you want to do extra steps you can use JSON

```
dataFields: any[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(this.model.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Object.assign for this:

dataFields: any[] = Object.assign([], this.model.columns);

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you are making a shallow copy, i.e. dataFields and tableColumns are alias (different names) to the same memory location. In angular, if you want to properly clone (make deep copy) an object or array, you will use the angular.copy(source, [destination]) method. Please look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) for detailed info. So, in your case if you define your variables as:

dataFields: any[] = angular.copy(this.model.columns)
        tableColumns: any[] = angular.copy(this.model.columns),

you can manipulate them independently.